# Android In-App Billing please sign in to Google account error

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-billing

I integrated Google IAP Billing to an Android application.

I published my application in Alpha version on Google Play Store. I copied the public key that I added in my project on Android Studio. So, I use the good Public API Key with my IabHelper instance.

I signed an APK that I use on a device with an unique account that is different from my developer account. This account is added in the license testing emails field on the Settings part of Google Play Developer Console.

I also checked the SKU ID of the item I want to purchase is the same on my application and on the application signed.

When I launch the buy process, I get a dialog with Please sign in to your google account error. But, I am already connected because I can go on Play Store application and download apps. I also tried to clear cache data for Play Store app and Google Play Services but nothing works for me.

I must mention that on the manage list of alpha testers, I have created a google+ community like asked but there is no link to send to my alpha-testers to opt-in.

Someone has an idea about the problem ? And the solution to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

The alpha tester has to satisfy these two conditions:

- joined the alpha testing community
- opted-in for alpha tests

Firs you have to invite the tester to the alpha testing community. Second the alpha tester have to opt-in using this URL: https://play.google.com/apps/testing/your.package.name

Answer (score 0):

It just takes time. Give it couple of hours and it will work.
Also make sure that the file you are running on your phone is signed with the sane certificate that is uploaded on google play (not debug file)